Как сделать цвет текста кнопки в фон заднего изображения?
Я уже перепробовала множество вариантов начиная от transparent, заканчивая тем, что приведу ниже в коде. Но получается то, да не то. Белый цвет угасает и становится более полупрозрачным, не сходится с макетом.

Нужно чтобы выглядело следующим образом:



.header__top-menu .menu__btn {
  border-radius: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 24.52px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.header__top-menu .menu__btn:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.header__top-menu .menu__btn:hover span {
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
}

.header__top-menu .menu__btn span {
  background-image: url(../img/main-picture.jpeg);
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 currentColor;
}
<nav class="header__top-menu">
  <button class="menu__btn">
  <span>Black sea Wine route</span>
   </button>
  <button class="menu__btn">
   <span>Armenia</span>
 </button>
  <button class="menu__btn">
   <span>Georgia</span>
   </button>
  <button class="menu__btn">
<span>Ukraine</span>
  </button>
  <button class="menu__btn">
  <span>Greece</span>
    </button>
</nav>




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56482378/how-to-fill-text-of-a-child-with-the-background-image-of-the-parent

Если кнопки чёрные или белые, то проще всего воспользоваться режимами наложения:


body { background: 0 0 / cover url('https://i.sstatic.net/1wjXBT3L.jpg') no-repeat; height: 100vh; text-align: center; }

.header__top-menu .menu__btn {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
  font: bold 16px/1.5em 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 2px currentcolor;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header__top-menu .menu__btn.black { color: black; }
.header__top-menu .menu__btn.white { color: white; }

.header__top-menu .menu__btn span {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em 1.5em;
  border-radius: inherit;
  transition: .4s ease;
}
.header__top-menu .menu__btn:hover span { filter: invert(1); }
.header__top-menu .menu__btn.black span { background-color: white; mix-blend-mode: multiply; }
.header__top-menu .menu__btn.white span { background-color: black; mix-blend-mode: screen; }
<nav class="header__top-menu">
  <button class="menu__btn black"><span>Black sea Wine route</span></button>
  <button class="menu__btn white"><span>Armenia</span></button>
  <button class="menu__btn black"><span>Georgia</span></button>
  <button class="menu__btn white"><span>Ukraine</span></button>
  <button class="menu__btn black"><span>Greece</span></button>
</nav>




Можно использовать градиент не снизу кнопок, а сверху. И сделать его прозрачным для мыши.


.header__top-menu {
    --bg-color: #88bbbb;
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    position: relative;
}

.header__top-menu .menu__btn {
  border-radius: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 24.52px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.header__top-menu .menu__btn:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: var(--bg-color);
}

.shade {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0.5),rgba(255,255,255,0));
}
<nav class="header__top-menu">
  <button class="menu__btn">
  Black sea Wine route
   </button>
  <button class="menu__btn">
   Armenia
 </button>
  <button class="menu__btn">
   Georgia
   </button>
  <button class="menu__btn">
    Ukraine
  </button>
  <button class="menu__btn">
    Greece
  </button>
  <div class="shade"></div>
</nav>




background-image: url(../img/main-picture.jpeg);  , а у вас background-color: var(--bg-color);

Да, согласен. Если в макете фон представляет собой сложную картинку, то моё решение не подходит. Но если простой градиент, то можно обойтись без картинки.

Чтобы сделать цвет текста кнопки соответствующим цвету фона заднего изображения, можно использовать несколько подходов в зависимости от того, что именно вам надо.
1. CSS (статический подход)
Если фон кнопки статичен, вы можете просто выбрать цвет текста, который будет гармонировать с фоном. Например:


body {
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  /* Укажите путь к вашему изображению */
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* Прозрачный фон */
  color: white;
  /* Цвет текста */
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Кнопка с цветом текста</title>

</head>

<body>
  <button class="button">Нажми на меня</button>
</body>

</html>



2. CSS с использованием mix-blend-mode
Если вы хотите, чтобы текст кнопки изменялся в зависимости от фона, вы можете использовать свойство mix-blend-mode. Этот метод позволяет комбинировать цвета текста и фона.


body {
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  /* Эффект смешивания */
  cursor: pointer;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Кнопка с смешиванием</title>

</head>

<body>
  <button class="button">Нажми на меня</button>
</body>

</html>




Не понял, что нужно было сделать если честно, всё легко делается.


body {
  height: 94vh;
  background-color: #A7CBE4;
}
.header__top-menu .menu__btn {
  border-radius: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.header__top-menu .menu__btn:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.header__top-menu .menu__btn:hover span {
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  color: #A7CBE4;
}

.header__top-menu .menu__btn span {
  background-image: url(../img/main-picture.jpeg);
  background-clip: text;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 currentColor;
}
<nav class="header__top-menu">
  <button class="menu__btn">
  <span>Black sea Wine route</span>
   </button>
  <button class="menu__btn">
   <span>Armenia</span>
 </button>
  <button class="menu__btn">
   <span>Georgia</span>
   </button>
  <button class="menu__btn">
<span>Ukraine</span>
  </button>
  <button class="menu__btn">
  <span>Greece</span>
    </button>
</nav>




color: #A7CBE4; не статичный, а цвет картинки заднего фона
